# Can't run Spring Boot app on eclipse tomcat embedded

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have a Spring Boot application that run without problem as java application but I can't run it in eclipse tomcat embedded.
I have already made the appropriate changes to create a war by maven but I have the following error:

Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.level] not found - trying original name [logging.level]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException
.......
and many similar mistakes

From command line or from eclipse I can run the app as Java Application (jar) and serve on port 8080 like default.
If run (debug mode) through eclipse tomcat embedded it fails here:

DefaultPropertyMapper.map (ConfigurationPropertyName) line: 49

49: String convertedName = configurationPropertyName.toString();

It fails only if i run tomcat in debug

Comment: Please, describe how do you run it. Why do you create a war? You should not have any problem if you run the application as regular java application using you spring boot application main class (the one annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: I need to run app on web container. When I add the app on tomcat embedded, it fails

Comment: It is not clear. Can you run application from command line with embedded tomcat? If you can't then how is the problem related to eclipse? You need to configure spring boot in the first place. Which spring boot starter (if any you used)? Show the dependencies you have in the pom.xml.

Comment: fails here: DefaultPropertyMapper.map (ConfigurationPropertyName) line: 49

49: String convertedName = configurationPropertyName.toString();

Comment: From command line or from eclipse I can run the app as Java Application (jar).
If run through eclipse tomcat embedded it fails

Comment: You should not add more information in comments. Update the post with the relevant information like _full_ stacktrace. Why the embedded web server that is run when you run spring boot as a java application does not work for you? The whole purpose of it is to easily run embedded web server, so why do you try to run it in a way it is not supposed to?

Comment: Because I need to deploy it in eclipse tomcat embedded where other applications run

Comment: It fails only if i run tomcat in debug :\

Comment: this can be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975657/unable-to-choose-tomcat-8-5-in-spring-tool-suite-when-running-spring-boot-applic